# PHP Page Does not Display Data Table

Tags: php, html

I have a search box that displays the search results in a table. The search box uses a simple search query to get the data from a database.

below is the code for the search box

```
 <form id="search-form" mmethod="post" action="search.php">
  <input name="searcher" id="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Type to Search">
  <input id="search-button" type="submit" value="Find">
</form
```

The PHP:

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="datacentre"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="data_centre_users"; // Table name 
$server_name="localhost";


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $searchword = $_POST['seacher'];  

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name , 3306);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}  

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE first_name='$searchword' OR last_name='$searchword' ";
$result = $con->query($sql);

$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();          

?>
<section id="sidebar">

</section>

<section id="content">

<div id="scroll-table">
<table >
<caption>
           Search Results
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <th class="center"><strong>ID</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>FirstName</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Request</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Purpose</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Description</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Booking Time</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Access Time</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Exit Time</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Approved</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Approved By</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Update</strong></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                // output data of each row
                while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['fisrt_name']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['last_name']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['request']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['purpose']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['description']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['booking_time']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['access_time']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['exit_time']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['approved']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['approved_by']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center" ><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                }
            }       
      ?> 
</table>
</div>
</section>
<

<aside></aside>

<?php
$con->close();
}
include('footer.php');
?>
```

When I run the code the page displayed is empty.

Comment: Please remove $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();  and then it will be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry dude, but there are a couple of issues here

firstly fix your form:
method="post" - not mmethod; type="text" - not type="search"; </form> - not </form

```
<form id="search-form" method="post" action="search.php">
  <input name="searcher" id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Type to Search">
  <input id="search-button" type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
```

secondly change:

```
if (isset($_POST['searcher'])) { // changed from submit
```

thirdly handle any errors in your query:

```
if (($result = $con->query($sql)) === false) {
  die("error: ".$con->error); // todo: improve error handling
}
```

fourthly remove this line:

```
$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

finally, for my sanity only, please remove this line (you really don't need it):

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
```

and it's matching:

```
}
```

and don't even get me started on escaping user input in case of SQL injection!

good luck, I hope you get this running

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following:

```
<form id="search-form" mmethod="post" action="search.php">
```

Should be:

```
<form id="search-form" method="post" action="search.php">
```

You need to escape it. The way it is now you are wide open to SQL-injection

```
$searchword = $_POST['seacher'];
```

So something like below. Also note the error : seacher / searcher in the `$_POST`

```
  $searchword = $con->real_escape_string( $_POST['searcher'] );
```

Put (``) backticks around table and column names to prevent "mysql reserved word error"

```
// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE `first_name` = '$searchword' OR `last_name` = '$searchword' ";
```

Remove the first fetch because it will interfere with the other

```
$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Just keep the one just before your table

```
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

Note the error in your table

```
<td class="center"><?php echo $rows['first_name']; ?></td> <!-- ['fisrt_name'] -->
```

For your

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
```

You could add the following:

```
} else {
  echo 'Nothing found'; 
}
```

Comment: he can't call real_escape_string() until `$con` is instantiated, so he needs to move the `new mysqli()` line up - I'd given up by the time I'd got to this, it would have been quicker to rewrite the scripts

Comment: @WeeZel Yes I know but he atleast should escape the user input with something. And in this case I was just giving a option as there are many more options to escape user input. Also note that it shouldn''t make much of a difference for him to move the connection a few lines up as he already declares the credentials needed at the top of the file

Comment: sadly with errors in both the html and the php code I think this one really needs to be hand held all the way

Comment: That's up to the OP but I think with all the answers here most of the errors in this script should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In you HTML, Input must has a name that you are trying to post.

```
<form id="search-form" method="post" action="search.php"> //spelling correction as you have type mistake mmethod
  <input name="searcher" id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Type to Search">
  <input id="search-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Find">
</form>
```

and in your PHP make sure you are posting;

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Find"){
```

AND try like this;

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM '$tbl_name' WHERE first_name='$searchword' OR last_name='$searchword' ";
```

OR

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE first_name='$searchword' OR last_name='$searchword' ";
```

AND

```
// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE first_name='$searchword' OR last_name='$searchword' ";
$result = $con->query($sql);

$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();   //Remove this you don't need it
?>
```

Because later you are running a loop here

```
<?php
if($result->num_rows > 0){
// output data of each row
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$result->fetch_assoc()` this line two times in your code so your query has only 1 result then 1 result is comes in first statment then when you tries second time used before html of your table you get nothing.